# GoogleMaps widget error Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, dart-pub

I have the following error when entering a page with Google Maps widget

```
W/DynamiteModule(17290): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule(17290): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:7
I/DynamiteModule(17290): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 7
W/SnapshotHandler(17290): Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.alguien.alguienchile, using defaults.
W/SnapshotHandler(17290): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.alguien.alguienchile/files/phenotype/shared/com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.alguien.alguienchile.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at zn.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at zi.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at aac.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at aab.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at zf.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):0)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at xf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):3)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at xk.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at yj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):14)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at avn.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):0)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at fw.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):26)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at fv.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):71)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at fv.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):0)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at iv.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at im.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at jn.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at jn.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at jn.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at jr.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):69)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8514)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
W/SnapshotHandler(17290):   ... 22 more
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290): Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.alguien.alguienchile, may result in stale flags.
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.alguien.alguienchile, sha256=[6ccda484a9aa71ed537b69996b0dfde9ea4d62512b74852fe813223d42d868fb], atk=false, ver=221820037.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at ahi.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at ahi.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at ais.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at xk.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at xm.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):0)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.alguien.alguienchile, sha256=[6ccda484a9aa71ed537b69996b0dfde9ea4d62512b74852fe813223d42d868fb], atk=false, ver=221820037.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2385)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2294)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at ei.ba(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at ra.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):4)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at io.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at jn.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at jn.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at jn.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at jr.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820081@22.18.20 (150400-0):69)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(17290):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Error occurs only on Android (including physical device).
App does not crush, Google Maps widget is showing correctly.
I have API activated for

```
Distance Matrix API
Maps SDK for Android
Maps SDK for iOS
Places API
```

API key mentioned correctly in the AndroidManifest.

```
 <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="*****"/>
```

Latest version of google_map_flutter

```
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
```

Dependencies look like this

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
     
    }
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Hi @Marchuk, I am having the same issue today. It was working fine yesterday for me.

Comment: It seems like this is something a few others (including myself) are facing. It's on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313).

Comment: Any update, I'm facing the same problem?

Comment: i am facing same issue

Comment: Facing same problem on some devices not all of them

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error using Xamarin Android. I fixed by editing **AndroidManifest.xml** following [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup)

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_MAP_IP_KEY"></meta-data>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I only had to add the `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` line to fix similar errors coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar kind of error
following things I have done

1.flutter clean
2. check app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml  file
and add

```
<manifest ...
<application ...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

here you can found "YOUR KEY" in project located in console
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
make sure you do not restrict API